# Expedia API book.api.ean.com blank

Tags: php, xml, json, rest

Im looking to book a hotel with expedia api

https://book.api.ean.com/

but the url is always blank,

details here using rest/json

http://developer.ean.com/docs/hotels/version_3/book_reservation/

I've seen a few people experiencing the same problem and wondered if anyone knew what it was

https://book.api.ean.com/ean-services/rs/hotel/v3/res?cid=55505
&apiKey=xxx
&locale=en_US
&currencyCode=USD
&customerUserAgent=Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/535.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/17.0.963.83 Safari/535.11
&customerIpAddress=127.0.0.1
&room1=1,3
&room1FirstName=TestBooking
&room1LastName=TestBooking
&room1BedTypeId=13
&room1SmokingPreference=NS
&room2=1,5
&room2FirstName=TestBooking
&room2LastName=TestBooking
&room2BedTypeId=13
&room2SmokingPreference=NS
&email=xxx
&firstName=TestBooking
&lastName=TestBooking
&homePhone=TestBooking
&workPhone=TestBooking
&creditCardType=CA
&creditCardNumber=5401999999999999
&creditCardIdentifier=123
&creditCardExpirationMonth=11
&creditCardExpirationYear=2012
&address1=travelnow
&city=Bellevue
&stateProvinceCode=WA
&countryCode=US
&postalCode=98004
&customerSessionId=0ABAA871-3127-A913-6642-A1F86D902E2B
&hotelId=211540
&arrivalDate=12/10/2012
&departureDate=12/12/2012
&supplierType=E
&rateKey=d03a8d29-1df2-4436-81d6-6b37eb4dcb78
&roomTypeCode=352749
&rateCode=1279169
&chargeableRate=803.04

including or excluding the minorrev doesn't seem to make much difference

Comment: I trust the cc info posted in url is test data...

Comment: yes Mike its the api test card info :)

Comment: Are you constructing these url query params to pass to the booking url?

Comment: yes but I get no response from the url at all??

Comment: just to confirm, the fix for this is to send the request as a POST, even though it uses querystring parameters

Comment: @MichaelLWatson: Hi. I am Getting the same problem blank page on book reservation. please help me to solve it. How you solve the problem.

Thanks in advance Waiting for reply

Comment: @chirag Nandwani you have to send the request as a post, even though it has querystring parameters, you post to the URL

Comment: @MichaelLWatson: I can not get the idea. can you please elaborate in details. thanks for the help

Comment: Same as you would with a form although I used this class http://www.phpclasses.org/httpclient <form method="post" action="https://book.api.ean.com/ean-services/rs/hotel/v3/res?cid=55505 &apiKey=xxx &locale=en_US &currencyCode=USD &customerUserAgent=Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/535.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/17.0.963.83 Safari/535.11 &customerIpAddress=127.0.0.1 &room1=1,3"><input name="submit" type="submit" /></form> chrome poster is also useful https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/chrome-poster/cdjfedloinmbppobahmonnjigpmlajcd?hl=en

Comment: @MichaelLWatson: Thanks alot for the help. I just want to ask one more think how do i fetch value from this link using json

Comment: I used the XML version, not sure if there is a JSON one

Comment: @MichaelLWatson: ok, please tell me the method of fetching value using xml. Because whenever click the book button then post this url it will transfer to the xml responce . But i want that only itinerary id will be shown on a php page . How can i get that?

Comment: @MichaelLWatson: I got the method using json. Thanks for the help in many ways.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try urlencoding each querystring parameter:

```
customerUserAgent=Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/535.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/17.0.963.83 Safari/535.11

arrivalDate=12/10/2012
```

The customerUserAgent url param should be url encoded:

```
customerUserAgent=Mozilla%2F5.0%20(Windows%20NT%206.1)%20AppleWebKit%2F535.11%20(KHTML%2C%20like%20Gecko)%20Chrome%2F17.0.963.83%20Safari%2F535.11

arrivalDate=12%2F10%2F2012
```

Take a look at PHP's [urlencode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php) for more information.

Also, be sure to remove the spaces between each querystring param, not sure if it was copy/paste issue or not.

Comment: yeah thanks you definitely helped me get there, it was a number of things that were wrong, including using GET instead of POST and your solution, thanks

Comment: i am in similar problem . will you please help me

Comment: @rahularyansharma: Post your question, myself or others should be able to help you.