# Yii framework blank page issue for many times

Tags: php, .htaccess, error-handling, yii, runtime-error

I am working in yii framework. my site many times problem in blank page issue. i am trying many ways but its not work properly. i am already trying increase **maximum execution** time. but its not work.its not showing any errors. also trying `error_reporting(1);`. this error not showing all times.

My htaccess file code is give below.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
       RewriteEngine On
       RewriteBase /
       RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
       RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
       RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

How can i solve this blank page problem. Please guide me.

Comment: Try to check the server error log, it might give you some hint on what is going on...

Comment: @David Constantine  this error only appear in error log file : Fatal error:  Wrong parameters for Exception([string $exception [, long $code [, Exception $previous = NULL]]]) in /var/www/buyjapon/root/protected/components/GBingTranslator.php on line 173

Comment: Also this issue appear inconsistent

Comment: So it seems to me that you have a problem in GBingTranslator.php on line 173

Comment: @NathanSrivi: Sorry For write my problem here. I saw your answer regarding EAN API. I am getting problem When i use book reservation tab from api tester. Can you please help me Regarding that. Thanks in advance

Comment: @chirag Nandwani ya sure. post your question and give me your question link. i will help you

Comment: @NathanSrivi: here is the url for my question: `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9948762/expedia-api-book-api-ean-com-blank'
 When i try to access ean api book reservation page response. it displays a blank page and i can not get xml.
 Hlp me to solve it out

Comment: @chirag Nandwani post your own question with your trying code. Then only i will give you a good solution for you

Comment: @NathanSrivi: There is a chance for repeat of question. I just go to the API tester and click on book reservation tab there is output after process but when i click on link it is blank. "This is my question why is this blank?" Other tab working perfectly

Answer (score 1):

Yii can't handle **fatal error** (Yii2 support it by using `error_get_last()` and `register_shutdown_function()`).

So you should check you php error log and get the reason.

Answer (score 0):

What about check to see if there are any space before or after the `<?php` inside view , controller, model file.

i mean at the top of the script, since it will output space, and making the redirect not functioning without showing error.

I had mine solved by found this.

Answer (score 0):

I found one of many the solution for this problem. In my case, there is one Controller that can't be redirected but others is good. All script are good, config and others are good too, then i realize  when i "Ctrl + a" on my editor that i have so many "ENTER" and "SPACE" and "TAB" after php closing tag "?>". Then i remove that blank space, that's it my "redirect" is working again. I hope it helps.